# How to know the active number of user connections / sessions to the IIS sites

Tags: asp.net, iis

How to know the currently active number of user connections/sessions to the IIS sites on a web server running on Windows Server?

Also, I need a report of a day which shows concurrent users along with time and/or Average, min, max concurrent users in a day.

Comment: If you want to View the Number of Active User Sessions on Your IIS Website you could use the performance monitor tool. you could refer this [link](http://woshub.com/how-to-monitor-active-sessions-on-iis/) for more detail.

Comment: I have tried current connection performance counter but seems it not giving the correct result. I access the web site from 3 browsers and current connection count reached to 10.

Comment: which command did you run to see the active connection?

Comment: Added Web Service -> Current Connections performance counter in the performance monitor for a specific IIS site.

Comment: open PowerShell as administrator and run this command `Get-Counter -Counter “\Web Service(*)\Current Connections”` it will show the current number of active connections on the IIS server **abc** is the name of the site. if you want to know the current active connection of the specific server you can run the `Get-Counter "web service(Site1)\current connections" -ComputerName web-srv01`